# Backbone RESTful sync : Impossible to enable PUT and DELETE on IIS 7.5

Tags: rest, iis, backbone.js, crud

I tried all the solutions found on Stack Overflow, with no success.

My web.config contains :

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

And I always get :

[image]

In my app, I did:

```
this.model.save({ firstname: name[0], lastname: name[1] });
```

And my collection is:

```
app.AttendeeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'http://test-backbone/attendee',
    model: app.AttendeeModel
});
```

My C#:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Put)]
public JsonResult Index(int id, Attendee updatedAttendee)
{
    var attendee = db.Attendees.Where(a => a.id == id).FirstOrDefault();

    attendee.firstname = updatedAttendee.firstname;
    attendee.lastname = updatedAttendee.lastname;

    db.SaveChanges();

    return Json(attendee, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```

## Questions

- Any idea?
- Is there a way to replace PUT and DELETE with POST? :(

---

## Full Controller (MVC 4, Internet Application, local IIS, Win 7)

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using AttendeeManager.Models;

namespace AttendeeManager.Controllers
{
    public class AttendeeController : Controller
    {
        AttendeeEntities db = new AttendeeEntities();

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public JsonResult Index(int? id)
        {
            if (id.HasValue)
            {
                var attendee = db.Attendees
                    .Where(a => a.id == id)
                    .Select(a => new { id = a.id, firstname = a.firstname, lastname = a.lastname })
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                return Json(attendee, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                var attendees = db.Attendees
                    .Select(a => new { id = a.id, firstname = a.firstname, lastname = a.lastname })
                    .ToList();

                return Json(attendees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public JsonResult Index(Attendee createdAttendee)
        {
            db.Attendees.AddObject(createdAttendee);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Json(createdAttendee, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Put)]
        public JsonResult Index(int id, Attendee updatedAttendee)
        {
            var attendee = db.Attendees.Where(a => a.id == id).FirstOrDefault();

            attendee.firstname = updatedAttendee.firstname;
            attendee.lastname = updatedAttendee.lastname;

            db.SaveChanges();

            return Json(attendee, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Delete)]
        public JsonResult Index(int id)
        {
            var attendee = db.Attendees.Where(a => a.id == id).FirstOrDefault();

            db.Attendees.DeleteObject(attendee);

            db.SaveChanges();

            return Json(attendee, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your entire attendee controller? Is this local or on your server? 7.5 iis should definitely support all verbs. If it is at all feasible, I would start a new project using Web API. Much cleaner and integrates with Backbone seamlessly. Although the above should still work.

Comment: @TyroneMichael - Done. Thanks for the help. Not a real app, just a technical demo about Backbone.js for my R&D team. So if all verbs don't work, I'll use set/remove instead of save/destroy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`emulateHTTP`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-emulateHTTP):

> **emulateHTTP** `Backbone.emulateHTTP = true`
>
> If you want to work with a legacy web server that doesn't support Backbones's default REST/HTTP approach, you may choose to turn on `Backbone.emulateHTTP`. Setting this option will fake `PUT` and `DELETE` requests with a HTTP `POST`, setting the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header with the true method.

You might need to tweak the server code to look at `X-HTTP-Method-Override` as well.